# Update/insert/retrieve accented character in DB?

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I am using oracle 12G

when i run `@F:\update.sql` from sql plus it  displays accented character `é` as junk character when I retrieve from either sqlplus or sql developer

By when run the individual statement from sql plus. Now if I retrieve it from sqlplus, it displays the correct character, but when I retrieve it from sqldeveloper, it again displays the junk character.

update.sql content is this

```
update employee set name ='é' where id= 1;
```

What i want is when i run @F:\update.sql , it should insert/update/retrieve it in correct format whether it is from sqlplus or any other tool ?

For information :- when i run

```
   SELECT * FROM NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS  WHERE PARAMETER LIKE '%CHARACTERSET%'
```

i get below information

```
PARAMETER                      VALUE
------------------------------ ----------------------------------------
NLS_CHARACTERSET               WE8MSWIN1252
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET         AL16UTF16
```

when i run `@.[%NLS_LANG%]` from command prompt i see

```
SP2-0310: unable to open file ".[AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8MSWIN1252]"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not familiar with SQL Developer but I can give solution for SQL*Plus.

Presume you like to work in Windows [CP1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)

First of all ensure that the file `F:\update.sql` is saved in CP1252 encoding. Many editors call this encoding `ANSI` which is the same (let's skip the details about difference between term `ANSI` and `Windows-1252`)

Then before you run the script enter

`chcp 1252`

in order to switch encoding of your `cmd.exe` to CP1252. By default encoding of `cmd.exe` is most likely [CP850](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850) or [CP437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) which are different.

Then set `NLS_LANG` environment variable to character set `WE8MSWIN1252`, e.g.

`set NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8MSWIN1252`

After that your script should work fine with SQL*Plus. SQL*Plus inherits the encoding (or "character set", if you prefer this term) from parent `cmd.exe`. `NLS_LANG` tells the Oracle driver which character set you are using.

Example Summary:

```
chcp 1252
set NLS_LANG=.WE8MSWIN1252
sqlplus username/password@db @F:\update.sql
```

Some notes: In order to set encoding of `cmd.exe` permanently, see this answer: [Unicode characters in Windows command line - how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line-how/33475373#33475373)

`NLS_LANG` can be set either as Environment Variable or in your Registry at `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ORACLE\KEY_%ORACLE_HOME_NAME%\NLS_LANG` (for 32-bit Oracle Client), resp. `HKLM\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_%ORACLE_HOME_NAME%\NLS_LANG` (for 64-bit Oracle Client).

For SQL Developer check you options, somewhere it should be possible to define encoding of SQL files.

You are not forced to use Windows-1252. The same works also for other encoding, for example `WE8ISO8859P1` (i.e. ISO-8859-1, `chcp 28591`) or UTF-8. However, in case of UTF-8 your SQL-script may contain characters which are not supported by database character set WE8MSWIN1252. Such characters would be replaced by placeholder (e.g. `¿`).

Comment: It does not work. What i did is 1) Open CMD 2) run `chcp 1252` which outputs `Active code page: 1252` 3)Then i run `@F:\update.sql` 4) I retrieve the updated data, it again gives me junk code

Comment: I tried `set NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8MSWIN1252` But it does not make any difference ?

Comment: Yes i am 100 %  sure it is saved as ANSI.Will you be able to try it at your end ?

Comment: What do you get by `select dump(name, 1016) from employee where id= 1;`

Comment: it gives `inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLO`. Actually name column is clob

Comment: Then do `select dump(to_char(name), 1016) from employee where id= 1;`

Comment: it returns `Typ=1 Len=1 CharacterSet=WE8MSWIN1252: e9`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128727/discussion-between-wernfried-domscheit-and-user3198603).